# netbeans regext for exclude files and folders from IDE

Tags: netbeans, ide, exclude

I need to be exclude these pattern from netbeans IDE.

```
  vendor/*/tests/* exclude all files under tests folder
  vendor/*/test/* exclude all files under test folder
  !vender/.*\.php  exclude all files that not has .php extension
```

I put these pattern to Ignored files patterns but did not work. Is there anything i missed?

```
vendor/*/tests/*|vendor/*/test/*|!vender/.*\.php
```

Thanks

Comment: The default pattern is this: ^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore|npmignore|jshintrc|bowerrc|travis\.yml)$).*$

Comment: I know about default pattern but seems be i cant add my pattern :(